# how to set blackberry path in Titanium

Tags: blackberry, path, titanium

i started developing apps in Titanium,in that i have already set android sdk path in Titanum but my problem is while setting blackberry path it will not allow to set,so let me know about blackberry path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a **paid user** before you can use the BlackBerry functionality. It is described correctly here how you can set everything: http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/blackberry/getting-started-beta-preview

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use blackberry for titanium https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_blackberry